# Single SSH connection in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I've created my Jenkinsfile for building my project in production and the pipeline looks like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Pull') {
      steps {
        sh '''ssh ${SSH_USER}@${SERVER_ADDRESS} <<EOF
              cd ${SOURCE_FOLDER}/project 
              git pull
              git status
           EOF'''
      }
    }
    stage('Composer') {
      parallel {
        stage('Composer') {
          steps {
            sh '''ssh ${SSH_USER}@${SERVER_ADDRESS} <<EOF 
                  docker run --rm -v ${SOURCE_FOLDER}/project:/app composer/composer:latest install
               EOF'''
          }
        }
        stage('Composer 2') {
          steps {
            sh '''ssh ${SSH_USER}@${SERVER_ADDRESS} <<EOF
                  docker run --rm -v ${SOURCE_FOLDER}/project/sub:/app 
composer/composer:latest install
               EOF'''
          }
        }
      }
   }
  }
 }
```

Is there a way to have all the stages all in one single SSH connection in order to minimise the overhead and the connection number?

I've done all the SSL stuff manually by creating the keys and pasting the public key on the production machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function for the connection and pass the SSH_USER & SERVER_ADDRESS as input parameters to that function. Call this function from all your stages.